# How to use multiple OR and & clause in one IF condition?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use multiple OR and & clause in 1 IF condition using javascript.

but my code doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```js
localStorage.setItem('subbed', 'yes');

var isFree = '0';

if ((isFree == '0' && localStorage.getItem('subbed') == null) ||
  (isFree == '0' && localStorage.getItem('strip_subbed') == null)) {
  console.log('locked');
} else {
  console.log('not locked');
}
```

if you run my code, its always `alert('locked')` which is wrong. Because the `subbed` `localstorage` is being set before everything else and it is not **null**.

so what I basically need to do is to look `IF` the `localstorage subbed OR stripe_subbed is not null and isFree variable is not 0` and then unlock something (alert('not locked') in this instance).

I hope i make sense and someone can help me.

Here's a working fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/13Lbdmqr/

Comment: "*because the subbed localstorage is being set before everything else and it is not null.*" - in the code you posted, that's a `getItem` call, not a `setItem` one.

Comment: @Bergi, that is a typo. even if you change that to setItem, it still alert('locked').

Comment: Your condition is `(A && S1) || (A && S2)`; and since A and S2 are both true, the result is also true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change your first line from

```
localStorage.getItem("subbed", "yes")
```

to

```
localStorage.setItem("subbed", "yes");
```

Next we need to examine your condition

If the localStorage item `subbed` OR `strip_subbed` is `null` you get `locked`

Something like this is more what you want:

```
if(isFree === '0' && (localStorage.getItem("subbed") === null && localStorage.getItem("strip_subbed") === null)) {
    alert("locked")
}
```

I find for compound things like this it can be nice to move your conditions into variables with good names to make it easy to reason about.

```
var isSubbed = localStorage.getItem("subbed") !== null;
var isStripSubbed = localStorage.getItem("strip_subbed") !== null;

if(isFree !== '0' && (isSubbed || isStripSubbed)){
    alert("not locked");
} else {
    alert("locked");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have expressed your condition in english better than in code... ;-)

```
if ((localStorage.getItem('subbed') !== null || localStorage.getItem('strip_subbed') !== null) && isFree !== '0') alert('not locked');
else alert('locked');
```

That's it!

Comment: Thank you but this always returnes alert('not locked') even if i clear the storage! example: https://jsfiddle.net/13Lbdmqr/1/

Answer (score 0):

**You have two main options**:

1. `(localStorage.getItem('subbed') !== null || localStorage.getItem('subbed') !== null) && isFree !== '0'`
2. `!(localStorage.getItem('subbed') === null && localStorage.getItem('subbed') === null) && isFree !== '0'`

---

To understand what's currently happening, let's break down the existing expression into steps. We start with:

```
(isFree == '0' && localStorage.getItem('subbed') == null) || 
(isFree == '0' && localStorage.getItem('strip_subbed') == null)
```

After we check `isFree == '0'`:

```
(true && localStorage.getItem('subbed') == null) ||
(true && localStorage.getItem('strip_subbed') == null)
```

After we check both cases of `localStorage.getItem(x) == null`:

```
(true && false) ||
(true && true)
```

Finally:

```
false || true
```

...This results in `true`. Like you said, this isn't what you wanted

---

To fix our understanding, we need to look closer at what you said:

> localstorage subbed OR stripe_subbed is not null and isFree variable is not 0

..."is not null" actually refers to two possible things in this sentence - subbed or stripe_subbed. So, this would be coded differently than you might say it:

```
(localStorage.getItem('subbed') !== null || localStorage.getItem('subbed') !== null) && isFree !== '0'
```

(The second option at the top of my answer comes from applying [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Negation_of_a_disjunction) to code)